# JSON Key not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My problem is that I have to POST a JSON object in the following format:

```
{ "key1": "value1",
  "key2": 2,
  "options": {
               "content": "lorem ipsum"
             }
}
```

But I keep getting an Internal server error: Key 'options' not found.
This is my js code:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
var json_test = { 
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": 2,
      "options": {
                   "content": "lorem ipsum"
                 }
    }
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/test/url/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:json_test
    })
});
```

And also this is the POST contents from Firebug:

```
element_type    Text
learning_page   1
options[content]    lorem ipsum
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but I just can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: may be "options" is reserved word?

Comment: What is your server-side code? The JS looks correct.

Comment: *Where* are you getting this error?

Comment: What is accepting the request? It would seem that's where the error is. Are you trying to deserialize the JSON into an object that doesn't have an "options" field?

Comment: Where are you posting this, and how are you retrieving the values on the server

Comment: Without more information we really cannot provide helpful answers. They are all guesses. My guess would be that you are trying to access the POST value with name `options`, but the actual name is `options[content]`.

Comment: And FWIW, your question has nothing to do with JSON. The variable `json_test` contains an **object**, not JSON.

Comment: I also forgot to add that it's using the Django REST Framework, and it has a api accessible through the browser and when i post the same json from there it works fine. This is the POST from firebug

_content { 
       "element_type":"Text", 
       "learning_page":1, 
        "options":{ 
            "content":"qwdqwdqwdqwdqwdqw" 
} }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but you  may be missing stringifying the json

```
$("#button").click(function(){
var json_test = { 
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": 2,
      "options": {
                   "content": "lorem ipsum"
                 }
    }
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/courses/api/elements/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:JSON.stringify(json_test)
    })
});
```

Also try adding

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

to your jquery options

Comment: If firebug is picking up the post data correctly, then it shouldn't need to be stringified. jQuery seems to do that automatically when receiving an object.

Comment: Depends on how the server expects the data.

Comment: stringifying doesn't help aswell

Comment: try adding this contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" to your jquery options

Comment: interesting, adding the contentType gives this error: {"detail": "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"}

EDIT: stringifying afterwards fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: stringifying is definitely a requirement, otherwise jQuery will convert it to a parameterized string. You also must include the contentType if the server is expecting it.